# Read Variable from URL Encoded Array with Square Brackets

Tags: java

I am trying to read a request variable in from saveData.jsp, where there are encoded square brackets.  Something like:

```
URL: saveData.jsp?name%5B%5D=Test1&name%5B%5D=Test2
String[] name = null;
if (request.getParameterValues("name") != null){
   name = request.getParameterValues("name");
}
```

The above code works when the URL doesn't have the brackets:

```
URL: saveData.jsp?name=Test1&name=Test2
```

How would I do the same thing with the brackets?

Comment: Are you using a framework, or raw servlets?

Comment: Using jQuery to submit the request.  The params are in an object, which is why it turns out with the square brackets.  Can't do param.name as it will be overwritten with the next item.

Comment: So, on the server side, are you using a framework, or raw servlets?

Comment: Using Struts as server framework.

Comment: Struts, both versions, already support indexed properties-why are you accessing the request parameters directly? Also, you need to state the Struts version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for param with brackets

```
String[] name = null;
if (request.getParameterValues("name") != null){
   name = request.getParameterValues("name");
}else if(request.getParameterValues("name[]") != null){
   name = request.getParameterValues("name[]");
}
```

Comment: After I posted, I decided to try this and it worked.  Sometimes you overthink things.  Thanks!